# I have a problem saving the date I picked using date picker fragment to my database

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker, android-sqlite, android-dialogfragment

I have this problem saving the date I picked in a string variable in my database

I have already tried saving it formatted with a forward slash and not formatted as a whole number but none of these worked out for me 
I have it in a RecyclerView like a list of things that when you click on one of them it gives a list of details and the date picked is one of them 
I have also uninstalled the application and installed it again to avoid any confusion in the database

This is my **DataBaseHandler.java** class:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    Context ctx;
    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, Constants.DB_NAME, null,Constants.DB_VERSION);
        ctx = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+ Constants.DB_TABLE + "(" +Constants.KEY_ID +
                " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ," + Constants.KEY_MANUF
                +" TEXT ," + Constants.KEY_NAME +" TEXT ,"+ Constants.KEY_MODEL +" INTEGER ,"+
                Constants.KEY_IMAGE+" TEXT ," + Constants.KEY_MILEAGE +" TEXT ,"+ Constants.KEY_OILDATE +" TEXT );";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+Constants.DB_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public void addCar(Cars carro){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        // todo: try flipping them for errors
        values.put(Constants.KEY_NAME,carro.getCarName());
        values.put(Constants.KEY_MODEL,carro.getCarModel());
        values.put(Constants.KEY_MANUF,carro.getCarManuf());
        values.put(Constants.KEY_IMAGE,carro.getCarImage());
        values.put(Constants.KEY_MILEAGE,carro.getCarMileage());
        values.put(Constants.KEY_OILDATE,carro.getCarOilDate());
        // the insertion of the row
        db.insert(Constants.DB_TABLE,null,values);
    }
    // get the cars
    public Cars getCars(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor miCursor = db.query(Constants.DB_TABLE,new String[]{Constants.KEY_ID,Constants.KEY_MANUF,Constants.KEY_NAME,Constants.KEY_MODEL,Constants.KEY_IMAGE}
        ,Constants.KEY_ID + "=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},null,null,null,null);
        if (miCursor != null)
            miCursor.moveToFirst();

            Cars miCarro = new Cars();
            miCarro.setCarID(Integer.parseInt(miCursor.getString(miCursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_ID))));
            miCarro.setCarManuf(miCursor.getString(miCursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_MANUF)));
            miCarro.setCarName(miCursor.getString(miCursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_NAME)));
            miCarro.setCarModel(miCursor.getString(miCursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_MODEL)));
            miCarro.setCarImage(miCursor.getString(miCursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_IMAGE)));
            miCarro.setCarMileage(miCursor.getString(miCursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_MILEAGE)));
            miCarro.setCarOilDate(miCursor.getString(miCursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_OILDATE)));
            return miCarro;
    }
    //list all cars
    public List<Cars> getAllCars(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        List<Cars> misCarros= new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor miCursor = db.query(Constants.DB_TABLE,new String[]{Constants.KEY_ID,Constants.KEY_MANUF,Constants.KEY_NAME,Constants.KEY_MODEL,Constants.KEY_IMAGE,Constants.KEY_MILEAGE,Constants.KEY_OILDATE}
                ,null,null,null,null,Constants.KEY_MANUF+" ASC;");
        if (miCursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do{
                Cars miCarro = new Cars();
                miCarro.setCarID(miCursor.getInt(miCursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_ID)));
                miCarro.setCarManuf(miCursor.getString(miCursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_MANUF)));
                miCarro.setCarName(miCursor.getString(miCursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_NAME)));
                miCarro.setCarModel(miCursor.getString(miCursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_MODEL)));
                miCarro.setCarImage(miCursor.getString(miCursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_IMAGE)));
                miCarro.setCarMileage(miCursor.getString(miCursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_MILEAGE)));
                miCarro.setCarOilDate(miCursor.getString(miCursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.KEY_OILDATE)));
                // add the shitty Car to the big list :)
                misCarros.add(miCarro);
            }while(miCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return misCarros;
    }
    //update Cars
    public int updateCars(Cars carros){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        // todo: try flipping them for errors
        values.put(Constants.KEY_MANUF,carros.getCarManuf());
        values.put(Constants.KEY_NAME,carros.getCarName());
        values.put(Constants.KEY_MODEL,carros.getCarModel());
        values.put(Constants.KEY_IMAGE,carros.getCarImage());
        values.put(Constants.KEY_MILEAGE,carros.getCarMileage());
        values.put(Constants.KEY_OILDATE,carros.getCarOilDate());
        return db.update(Constants.DB_TABLE,values,Constants.KEY_ID + "=?",new String[] {String.valueOf(carros.getCarID())});
    }
    //delete cars
    public void deleteCars(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(Constants.DB_TABLE,Constants.KEY_ID + "=?",new String[] {String.valueOf(id)});
        db.close();
    }
    //get cars count
    public int getCarsCount(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor miCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+Constants.DB_TABLE,null);
        return miCursor.getCount();
    }
}
```

and this is my **RecyclerViewAdapter.java** file :

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private List<Cars> misCarros;
    private AlertDialog dialog;
    private AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder;
    private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE=1;
    public boolean clicked = false;
    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Cars> misCarros) {
        this.context = context;
        this.misCarros = misCarros;
    }

    public RecyclerViewAdapter() {
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_row,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view,context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Cars carro = misCarros.get(position);
        Bitmap pic;
        if(carro.getCarImage() != null) {
            pic = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(carro.getCarImage());
            holder.ImagenaDelCarro.setImageBitmap(pic); }
        holder.ManufacturarDelCarro.setText(carro.getCarManuf());
        holder.NombreDelCarro.setText(carro.getCarName());
        holder.ModelDelCarro.setText(carro.getCarModel());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return misCarros.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView ManufacturarDelCarro;
        public TextView NombreDelCarro;
        public TextView ModelDelCarro;
        public ImageView ImagenaDelCarro;
        public Button editarElCarro;
        public Button deletarElCarro;
        public int id;
        public ViewHolder(View view, final Context ctx) {
            super(view);
            context = ctx;
            ManufacturarDelCarro = view.findViewById(R.id.carManuf);
            NombreDelCarro = view.findViewById(R.id.carName);
            ModelDelCarro = view.findViewById(R.id.carDOB);
            ImagenaDelCarro = view.findViewById(R.id.carImage);
            editarElCarro = view.findViewById(R.id.editCarID);
            deletarElCarro = view.findViewById(R.id.deleteCarID);
            editarElCarro.setOnClickListener(this);
            deletarElCarro.setOnClickListener(this);
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    Cars car = misCarros.get(position);
                    Intent miIntento = new Intent(ctx, DetailsActivity.class);
                    miIntento.putExtra("name", car.getCarName());
                    miIntento.putExtra("model", car.getCarModel());
                    miIntento.putExtra("manuf", car.getCarManuf());
                    miIntento.putExtra("position", car.getCarID());
                    miIntento.putExtra("imagePath",car.getCarImage());
                    miIntento.putExtra("mileage",car.getCarMileage());
                    miIntento.putExtra("oilChangeDate",car.getCarOilDate());
                    ctx.startActivity(miIntento);

                }
            });

        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId())
            {
                case R.id.editCarID:
                    Cars unCarro = misCarros.get(getAdapterPosition());
                    editCar(unCarro);
                    break;
                case R.id.deleteCarID:
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    unCarro = misCarros.get(position);
                    deleteCar(unCarro.getCarID());
                    break;
            }

        }
        public void deleteCar (final int id)
        {
            final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
            alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            alertBuilder.setTitle(R.string.confTitle);
           // alertBuilder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.alert_dark_frame);
            alertBuilder.setMessage(R.string.confMsg);
            alertBuilder.setNegativeButton(R.string.noBu, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.yesBu, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    db.deleteCars(id);
                    misCarros.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                    notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    if (db.getCarsCount() <= 0)
                    {
                        context.startActivity(new Intent(context,MainActivity.class));
                        ((Activity)context).finish();
                    }
                }
            });
            dialog = alertBuilder.create();
            dialog.show();

        }
        public void editCar(final Cars car)
        {
            alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_car_popup,null);
            final EditText carName = view.findViewById(R.id.nCarName);
            final EditText carManuf = view.findViewById(R.id.nCarManuf);
            final EditText DOB = view.findViewById(R.id.nCarDOB);
            TextView editCarText = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            Button editImage = view.findViewById(R.id.addImageID);
            final ImageView carImage = view.findViewById(R.id.laImagenaPuta);
            final Button editCarButton = view.findViewById(R.id.addCarID);
            editImage.setText(R.string.editImageText);
            editCarButton.setText(R.string.editCarBu);
            editCarText.setText(R.string.editCarText);
            carManuf.setHint(R.string.manufHint);
            carName.setHint(R.string.nameHint);
            DOB.setHint(R.string.DOBHint);
            final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            alertBuilder.setView(view);
            dialog = alertBuilder.create();
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog.show();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            if(!clicked)
                editor.putString("imagePath",null);
            editor.apply();
            long time = SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis();
            editImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try{
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity)context, new String[]{
                                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                    REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        }else {
                            clicked = true;
                            Intent helperIntent = new Intent(context,IntentHelperActivity.class);
                            startActivity(context,helperIntent,null);
                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sharedPreferences.getString("imagePath", null));
                                    carImage.setImageBitmap(image);
                                }
                            }, 1690);
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            editCarButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final String imagePath = sharedPreferences.getString("imagePath", null);
                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
                    if(!carManuf.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                        car.setCarManuf(carManuf.getText().toString());
                    if(!carName.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                        car.setCarName(carName.getText().toString());
                    if(!DOB.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                        car.setCarModel(DOB.getText().toString());
                    if(imagePath != null)
                        car.setCarImage(imagePath);
                    db.updateCars(car);
                    notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition(), car);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context,ListActivity.class);
                    context.startActivity(myIntent);
                    ((Activity)context).finish();
                    ((Activity) context).finish();

                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

and this is my **DatePickerFragment.java** class

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{
    private static int year;
    private static int month;
    private static int day;
    private Cars car;
    private DatabaseHandler db;
    private Bundle miBundle;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Declaring Car object to use it to update the car's Oil change Date
        db =  new DatabaseHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        miBundle = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        car = new Cars();
        car.setCarID(miBundle.getInt("position"));
        car.setCarName((String) miBundle.get("name"));
        car.setCarManuf((String) miBundle.get("manuf"));
        car.setCarModel((String) miBundle.get("model"));
        car.setCarMileage((String) miBundle.get("mileage"));
        car.setCarImage((String) miBundle.get("imagePath"));
        car.setCarOilDate(miBundle.getString("oilChangeDate"));
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),this,year,month,day);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        TextView tv = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.oilChangeID);
        String formattedDate = year+" / "+ (month+1)+" / " +dayOfMonth;
        String unFormattedDate = ("f"+year+(month+1)+dayOfMonth+"f");
        tv.setText(formattedDate);
        car.setCarOilDate(unFormattedDate);
        db.updateCars(car);
        miBundle.putString("oilChangeDate",unFormattedDate);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),DetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtras(miBundle);
        getActivity().finish();
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

and finally this is my **DetailsActivity.java** class:

```
public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_DATE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private TextView nameDet;
    private TextView manufDet;
    private TextView modelDet;
    private ImageView imgDet;
    private Bitmap getImg;
    private TextView mileage;
    private TextView oilChangeDate;
    private Cars car;
    private int id;
    private AlertDialog dialog;
    private DatabaseHandler db;
    private AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder;
    private Bundle miBundle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
        miBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        nameDet = findViewById(R.id.carNameDet);
        manufDet = findViewById(R.id.carManufDet);
        modelDet = findViewById(R.id.carDOBDet);
        imgDet = findViewById(R.id.carImageDet);
        mileage = findViewById(R.id.mileage);
        oilChangeDate = findViewById(R.id.oilChangeID);
        db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        if (miBundle != null )
        {
            nameDet.setText((String) miBundle.get("name"));
            modelDet.setText(miBundle.getString("model"));
            manufDet.setText(miBundle.getString("manuf"));
            mileage.setText("Mileage : "+miBundle.getString("mileage"));
            oilChangeDate.setText(miBundle.getString("oilChangeDate"));
            if(miBundle.getString("imagePath") != null){
                getImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(miBundle.getString("imagePath"));
                imgDet.setImageBitmap(getImg);
                imgDet.setMaxHeight(190);
                imgDet.setMinimumHeight(180);
            }
            id = miBundle.getInt("position");
            car = new Cars();
            car.setCarID(miBundle.getInt("position"));
            car.setCarName((String) miBundle.get("name"));
            car.setCarManuf((String) miBundle.get("manuf"));
            car.setCarModel((String) miBundle.get("model"));
            car.setCarMileage((String) miBundle.get("mileage"));
            car.setCarImage((String) miBundle.get("imagePath"));
            car.setCarOilDate(oilChangeDate.getText().toString());
            db.updateCars(car);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,ListActivity.class));
    }

    public void setMileageBu(View view) {
        alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final View myView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.set_value,null);
        final EditText mileageValue = myView.findViewById(R.id.nCarMileage);
        Button setMileage = myView.findViewById(R.id.editMileageID);
        alertBuilder.setView(myView);
        miBundle.putString("oilChangeDate",mileageValue.getText().toString());
        dialog =alertBuilder.create();
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.show();
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this,DetailsActivity.class);
        setMileage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                car.setCarMileage(mileageValue.getText().toString());
                db.updateCars(car);
                mileage.setText("Mileage : "+mileageValue.getText().toString());
                miBundle.putString("mileage",mileageValue.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtras(miBundle);
                startActivity(intent,miBundle);
                finish();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
    public void setOilChangeDate(View view) {
        DialogFragment fragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"Un puta Date picker");
    }

}
```

I have ensured that the `RecyclerView` gets updated when I get back to it which works fine with setting the mileage but not when the date is picked.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: First thing to do is check the result of `db.updateCars(car);`. If it's greater then 0. Then the database has been updated. That splits the issue in half. i.e. if 0 then the database isn't being updated. If it is greater than 0 then the issue is either that the database isn't being updated with an appropriate value or that you are not getting the updated value correctly when making the determination that it isn't working.

Comment: Thanks mr.Mike but I am a little rookie and how do I get this ?

Comment: By using logcat U mean?

Comment: You could use `Log.d("UPDATERESULT","Number of rows updated = " + String.valueOf(db.updateCars(car));` to output to the log, run and then check the log.

Comment: not an issue with your updateCar method.Have tested this and it works OK. It relies on the id in the Cars object being correct. Suggest adding a break point at line `SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();`, clicking the little green bug to **Debug App** *(Shift f9)*. When updateCar is called it will stop and display the debug window (assuming Android Studio). As the Cars object is passed this will be listed in the Variables Window, expand **carros** and check the values. Is the oildate as expected? Is the id as expected?

Comment: For more on using breakpoints, check out [Work with breakpoints](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/#breakPoints). Check the whole page for other tips and techiques (any other IDE should have an equivalent). I've done a little, but simply put there is far too much code to try to replicate the issue. You'd need to follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (which would require whittling the issue down anyway).

Comment: Ok thanks Mr. Mike , I will try this.

Comment: Solved it, and it had nothing to do with the database, just silly of me, thank you very much Mr.Mike and I wish to repay you soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it, silly of me I didn't include the ListActivity.java class which is the core problem.
this is the onCreate method on it

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
//                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
//                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                createPopupDialog();
            }
        });
        db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        miRicicler = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewID);
        miRicicler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        miRicicler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        listaDeCarros = new ArrayList<>();
        listaDeItems = new ArrayList<>();
        listaDeCarros = db.getAllCars();
        for (Cars x : listaDeCarros)
        {
//            Cars car = new Cars("Manufacturer : " + x.getCarManuf()
//                    ,x.getCarName(),x.getCarID(),"Model : "+x.getCarModel());
           Cars car = new Cars();
           String carManufText = x.getCarManuf();
           String carModelText = x.getCarModel();
           if (carManufText.contains("Manufacturer : "))
               car.setCarManuf(x.getCarManuf());
           else{
               car.setCarManuf("Manufacturer : "+x.getCarManuf());
           }
           car.setCarName(x.getCarName());
           if (carModelText.contains("Model : "))
               car.setCarModel(x.getCarModel());
           else{
               car.setCarModel("Model : " + x.getCarModel());
           }
           car.setCarID(x.getCarID());
           car.setCarImage(x.getCarImage());
           car.setCarMileage(x.getCarMileage());
           car.setCarOilDate(x.getCarOilDate()); //I have solved it by adding this line
           listaDeItems.add(car);
        }
```

it was on the car.setCarOilDate line, I forgot to add it earlier and thought that the problem is maybe from updating the database from the dialogFragment.
Anyway thanks to Mr.Mike for the help.